# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Must declare the scalar variable "@ID".'

Tags: c#, asp.net

I keep getting the error message

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Must declare the scalar variable "@ID".' -

I have a gridview that captures what the user inputs into texts boxes and submits them to the database on a click of a button. When the user clicks the button I am also trying to store the current user logged in, into a database table. Can someone help me as to why this message keeps occurring?

Here is the C# code for my button click event

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string query = "insert into Stock_Take_Item(ItemID, BarQuantity, StorageQuantity) values(@ID, @BAR, @STORAGE); insert into Stock_Take(Username, StockDate)" +
            " values(@Username, GetDate())";

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
    con.Open();

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", Session["username"].ToString());

    foreach (GridViewRow row in gvStockTake.Rows)
    {
        Label ID = row.FindControl("itemId") as Label;
        TextBox BAR = row.FindControl("txtBar") as TextBox;
        TextBox STORAGE = row.FindControl("txtStorage") as TextBox;

        cmd.Parameters.Clear();

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ID.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@BAR", SqlDbType.Int).Value = BAR.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@STORAGE", SqlDbType.Int).Value = STORAGE.Text;

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); //query execution
    }

    con.Close();
    Response.Write("Successfully inserted stock take items.");
}
```

And here is the code to my Log in C# code

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(local)\;Initial Catalog=SmallBatch;Integrated Security=True;"))
    {
        sqlCon.Open();

        string query = "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Site WHERE Username=@username AND Password=@password";

        SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlCon);

        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtUsername.Text.Trim());
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtPassword.Text.Trim());

        int count = Convert.ToInt32(sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar());

        if (count == 1)
        {
            Session["username"] = txtUsername.Text.Trim();
            Response.Redirect("Dashboard.aspx");
        }
        else 
        { 
            lblErrorMessage.Visible = true; 
        }
    }
}
```

I am still new to ASP.NET and C#, so any recommendations are more than appreciated!

Comment: instead of `cmd.Parameters.Clear();` why not just reset the value? also, you do `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username",...` and then you clear it

Comment: Your query contains two distinct insert statements - I feel like these should be executed separately? That could be the issue.

Comment: @jocull not really. He can do it. In fact, may be just collect parameters into one big bulk, instead of separate execution of separate inserts. This way, only one trip to DB. Depends, how big is the total load

Comment: `SqlCommand` and `SqlConnection` are both disposable so should both be in a `using` block. The Dispose of the connection (as it exits the using block) handles the Close, so you don't need to. I'd suggest taking a look at [Can we stop using AddWithValue](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).

Comment: Clearing the parameters collection will clear your username (set before the loop). Did you mean that ?

Comment: A likely cause is that the value for `@ID` is `null` and you are not setting the value to be used to `System.DBNull.Value` and doing this the SqlCommand will ignore that parameter entirely. To fix it check if the value is null and if it is pass `System.DBNull.Value` instead to the value of the parameter. Also be sure you specify the appropriate SqlDbType in your parameter **and** pass the values in the type they are expected so if `Stock_Take_Item.ItemID` is `Int` then you should also use an `int` in your c# value and **not a string from a text box**.

Comment: hey, check my answer. It will put you on the **right** path

Answer (score 0):

I would do things in bulk - it will cut on number of trips to database

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    var counter = 0;
    var query = @"insert into Stock_Take_Item
                  (ItemID, BarQuantity, StorageQuantity)
                  values
              ({1}, {2}, {3});
               insert into Stock_Take
               (Username, StockDate) 
               values
               ({0}, GetDate());";

    var paramList = new List<SqlParameter>();
    var sqlBulk = new StringBuilder(10000);
    var p0 = "@0";
    var maxRows = 100;
    var currRow = 0;
    var totalRows = 0;

    foreach (GridViewRow row in gvStockTake.Rows)
    {
        Label ID = row.FindControl("itemId") as Label;
        TextBox BAR = row.FindControl("txtBar") as TextBox;
        TextBox STORAGE = row.FindControl("txtStorage") as TextBox;

        currRow++;        
        totalRows++;

        if (counter == 0)
        {
            paramList.Add(new SqlParameter(, Session["username"].ToString()));            
        }
        var p1 = "@" + ++counter;
        var p2 = "@" + ++counter;
        var p3 = "@" + ++counter;

        paramList.AddRange(new[]{
            new SqlParameter(p1, Convert.ToInt32(Id.Text),
            new SqlParameter(p2, Convert.ToInt32(BAR.Text),
            new SqlParameter(p3, Convert.ToInt32(STORAGE.Text)
            });

        sqlBulk.AppendFormat(query, p0, p1, p2, p3);

        if (currRow == maxRows || totalRows == gvStockTake.Rows)
        {
            using (var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlBulk.ToString(), con))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddRange(paramList);
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
            currRow = 0;
            counter = 0;
            paramList.Clear();
            sqlBulk.Length = 0;
        }

    }

}
```

**Disclaimer:** Not tested.